# VBA Macro SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to run this Query on Microsoft Excel using VBA. However when I pressed a Refresh Button, the Query does not run. Can you help me whats wrong?

Here are the code that I wrote

```
Sub testquery()
Dim mysql As New insql
mysql.company = Cells(2, 1)

Dim str

str = str + " SELECT T0.CardCode AS 'Customer Code', T0.CardName AS 'Customer Name', T3.SlpName AS 'Sales Person', T0.CreateDate AS 'BP Creation Date' "
str = str + " MIN(T1.DocDate) AS [CustomerFirstOrder], MAX(T1.DocDate) AS [CustomerLatestOrder], "
str = str + " T2.ItemCode AS 'Item Code', T2.Dscription AS 'Item Description', T2.Quantity AS 'Purchased Quantity', T2.DocDate AS 'Invoice Date', "
str = str + " T2.DocNum AS 'Invoice Number' "
str = str + " FROM OCRD T0 "
str = str + " INNER JOIN OINV T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode "
str = str + " INNER JOIN (SELECT GHa.ItemCode, Gha.Dscription, GHb.DocNum, GHb.DocDate, GHa.Quantity, Ghb.CardCode FROM OINV GHb  INNER JOIN INV1 GHa ON GHb.DocEntry = GHa.DocEntry  LEFT JOIN RIN1 GHc ON Ghc.BaseEntry = GHb.DocEntry AND GHc.BaseLine = GHa.LineNum LEFT JOIN ORIN GHd ON GHc.DocEntry = GHd.DocEntry GROUP BY GHb.CardCode, GHa.ItemCode, GHa.Dscription, GHb.DocNum, GHb.DocDate, GHa.Quantity) T2 ON T2.CardCode = T0.CardCode "
str = str + " INNER JOIN OSLP T3 ON T0.SlpCode = T3.SlpCode "
str = str + " INNER JOIN OITM T4 ON T2.ItemCode = T4.ItemCode"
str = str + " WHERE T0.CardType = 'C' AND T4.InvntItem = 'Y' "
str = str + " GROUP BY T0.CardCode, T0.CardName,T3.SlpName, T0.CreateDate, T2.ItemCode, T2.Dscription, T2.DocNum, T2.DocDate, t2.Quantity "
str = str + " ORDER BY T2.DocDate"

mysql.CommandText = str

mysql.aimcell = Cells(3, 1)
Range("3:100000").ClearContents
mysql.fillrecord
End Sub
```

Many Thanks

Comment: `Dim mysql As New insql` - what is `insql` here?   And "the Query does not run" means nothing at all happoens, or you get an error?

Comment: Hi Tim, insql is a module I created. I coded this inside module called insql. Yes nothing happens. It didn't give me errors. It just displayed nothing when I pressed a button to called the macro

Comment: What is it *supposed* to do when it runs?  Does it clear the rows from 3 to 100000?  Pretty difficult to help when the main code of your task is "behind the curtain" in `mysql`...

Comment: Hi Tim, the code should displayed things that I select from the SQL Query. It does clear the contents, but I didn't return me any results. When I try to run this code on SQL Management Studio it does give me the results I want

Comment: There's nothing we can do here - you're asking for help with invisible code...

Comment: you need to show us your insql module, specifically the aimcell implementation

Comment: Hi Tim and Villiger

I will revert back this to you as soon as possible. Thanks for your keen help